# Is it possible to combine the following two SQL statements into one?

Tags: sql, mysql

There are two SQL statements. One is

```
select count(*) from steventable where username='steven';
select * from steventable where username='steven' LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Is it possible to combine two SQL statements into one? The first one is to get how many records in steventable when username is steven, the second one is to fetch the first 30 records which username is steven.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's still two statements, using the [`FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function and `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` should do what you need and will be more efficient than two separate queries.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM steventable
WHERE username = 'steven'
LIMIT 0, 30;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: Genius.This is what I exactly want. Thank you, @Luke.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second query returns 30 rows; does that mean that you want every single row to also contain the total number of rows? In that case, you'd have to use subqueries

```
select *, (select count(*) from steventable where username='steven') allSteven from steventable where username='steven' LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

altho i think it makes more sense to split these up into distinct queries

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select count(*) from steventable where username='steven') AS the_count,
st.* from steventable st where st.username='steven' LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

I don't know why you need to do that, but can't come up with a good reason to combine those 2 queries into one.

Comment: I want to improve efficiency.